# Updating Selenium Python to v4.8.0 "options.headless = True" shows DeprecationWarning

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium4

I have followed the change exact but it doesn't work, are there any other bugs?

https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/

---

```
import time

import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True

options.page_load_strategy = 'none'

chrome_path = 'chromedriver.exe'
chrome_service = Service(chrome_path)

driver = Chrome(options=options, service=chrome_service)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

url= "https://hk.centanet.com/findproperty/list/transaction/%E6%84%89%E6%99%AF%E6%96%B0%E5%9F%8E_3-    DMHSZHHRHD?q=TiDxvVGMUUeutVzA0g1JlQ"

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)

contents = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[class*='bx--structured-list-tbody']")


properties = contents.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[class*='bx--structured-list-row']")

def extract_data(element):
    columns = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[class*='bx--structured-list-td']")
    Date = columns[0].text
    Dev = columns[1].text
    Price = columns[3].text
    RiseBox = columns[4].text
    Area = columns[5].text

return{
    "Date": Date,
    "Development": Dev,
    "Consideration": Price,
    "Change": RiseBox,
    "Area": Area
}

data = []

for property in properties:
    extracted_data = extract_data(property)
    data.append(extracted_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("result.csv", index=False)
```

---

Comment was as follows:

```
Selenium.py:10: DeprecationWarning: headless property is deprecated, instead use add_argument('--headless') or add_argument('--headless=new')
options.headless = True
```

I tried the changes suggested by https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/
but it doesn't work

Comment: The warning says to use `add_argument('--headless')` or `add_argument('--headless=new')` but you are doing `options.headless = True`

Comment: Thanks! but i have tried all of them just didnt put in the code

Answer (score 1):

This *warning* message...

```
DeprecationWarning: headless property is deprecated, instead use add_argument('--headless') or add_argument('--headless=new') options.headless = True
```

...is inline with the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) Blog post with the heading [*Headless is Going Away!*](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/)

---

### Details

Chromium team have released the Native Headless mode which is now officially the ***new Headless*** mode. This functionality is available with:

- *Chromium v109.0.5400.0*
- *ChromeDriver v109.0.5414.25*
- *Selenium v4.8.0*

The new syntax requires ***`--headless=new`*** to be passed as an argument as follows:

- *Java*:

  ```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("--headless=new");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://selenium.dev);
  driver.quit();
  ```
- *Python*:

  ```
  options = ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("--headless=new")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  driver.get('http://selenium.dev')
  driver.quit()
  ```
- *Javascript*:

  ```
  let driver = await env
    .builder()
    .setChromeOptions(options.addArguments('--headless=new'))
    .build();
  await driver.get('https://selenium.dev');
  await driver.quit();
  ```
- *CSharp*:

  ```
  var options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.AddArgument("--headless=new");
  var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://selenium.dev");
  driver.Quit();
  ```
- *Ruby*:

  ```
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Options.chrome(args: ['--headless=new'])
  driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
  driver.get('https://selenium.dev')
  driver.quit
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration:

```
# pip install selenium==4.8.0    

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options=Options()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")    
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"]) #Optional
service=Service(f"path\chromebrowser.exe")

browser=webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

print(browser.name)
```

[python](/questions/tagged/python)[selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium)[webdriver](/questions/tagged/webdriver)[options](/questions/tagged/options)

Comment: thanks. I have just tied your code and the following comment returned:

-------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\中原python Selenium.py" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\中原python Selenium.py", line 11, in <module>
    browser=webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
            ^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'webdriver' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Add the first line of import, my bad there.