# Cannot create account in Selenium with Headless Chrome Driver

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to create a user with Selenium because I don't have access to the database from my server. I get the message "PASS" but the user is never created so I thing it might be something related to headless.

Is there any way to use clicks and filling forms with headless?

**Setup**

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_service = ChromeService('/home/bitnami/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=self.chrome_service,options=self.chrome_options)
```

**Create user**

```
driver.get(URL)
driver.set_window_size(1657, 1006)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "username").send_keys(USER)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "password").send_keys(PASS)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "_submit").click()
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Ajustes").click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#administrator-salespersons span").click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fa-plus").click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn-sm").click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "sal_username").send_keys(USER2)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "sal_password").send_keys(PASS2)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "sal_email").send_keys(EMAIL)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "sal_Guardar").click()
driver.quit()
```

*Note:* I've tested in my computer without headless and it creates the user successfully. I don't get any error in the server. I've also searched all over the internet but all I've found are examples without clicks.

[Successful message after running pytest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG0dV.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
```

try:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new")
```

---

### Note

The prerequisite to use Native Headless mode i.e. ***`--headless=new`*** which is now officially called the ***new Headless*** mode are as follows:

- [**Chromium v109.0.5400.0**](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/releases/tag/109.0.5400.0)
- [**ChromeDriver v109.0.5414.25**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=109.0.5414.25/)

aptly supported through:

- [***Selenium v4.8.0***](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/selenium-4-8-0-released/)

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [DeprecationWarning: headless property is deprecated, instead use add_argument('--headless') or add_argument('--headless=new') on Selenium 4.8.0 Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75367068/7429447)
- [Updating Selenium Python to v4.8.0 "options.headless = True" shows DeprecationWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75417182/7429447)

Comment: why in my selenium 4.8 with chromedriver version 109.0.5414.74, unable to execute that arguments? Seems here the headless keep runing as normal instead of real headless. @undetectedSelenium